# Is it possible to send data through PHP into a HTML file?

Tags: php, html, xml

Through searching myself I've found solutions to send HTML data to PHP which I have already done however, I want to get data from an XML file that is accessed by a PHP script into a HTML file due to the format it is in. This is my current attempt. This does not work, where am I going wrong?

```
  <div class="w3-container w3-red w3-cell">
    <h4>Todays Projections</h4>
    <p>#OUTPUT THE CURRENT DATE + PROJECTION</p>
    <?php 
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("XMLtest.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    $nodes = $xml->xpath("/february/finances[@date='". date("d-m-Y") . "']");
    echo "Date: ";
      $attr = $nodes->attributes();
      echo $attr['date'];
      echo "<br> Projection: ";
      echo $nodes->projection . ",<br>Recommended Staff: ";
    echo $nodes->recommendedStaff . ",<br>Staff Wages: ";
    echo $nodes->staffWages . ",<br>Actual: ";
    echo $nodes->actual . "<br>";
    ?>
  </div>
```

Sample XML:

```
<february>
  <finances id="48" date="17-02-2017">
        <projection>101</projection>
        <recommendedStaff>10</recommendedStaff>
        <staffWages>101</staffWages>
        <actual>101</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="49" date="18-02-2017">
        <projection>101</projection>
        <recommendedStaff>10</recommendedStaff>
        <staffWages>101</staffWages>
        <actual>101</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="50" date="19-02-2017">
        <projection>101</projection>
        <recommendedStaff>10</recommendedStaff>
        <staffWages>101</staffWages>
        <actual>101</actual>
    </finances>
</february>
```

Edit:
PHP is working within other files hosted on the server and through my account. However I can't get it work in a HTML file like shown above.

Comment: That is the PRIME function of PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly Could you expand on your point as I am looking for guidance and information rather than a statement?

Comment: So what is the issue with this code?

Comment: To expand on what @RiggsFolly said, PHP is a templating language (e.g. to create HTML, but not limited to that). All you need to do is change your file extension to `.php` and write your PHP code inside of this file alongside HTML.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea if you show us at least a relevant sample of the XML file you are processing

Comment: @AlexJenkinson what is the error that you are getting. Saying it does not work, does not help. We need to know what is not working, what is erring out.

Comment: @AlexJenkinson post the XML structure, also i noticed that in function date you are missing the ')' closing parenthesis

Comment: Forgive me all I pasted the old code that was used in the PHP file itself. I will post a sample of the XML I am looking to access.

Comment: @djthoms Therefore would I need to embed it such as done in this HTML file? As I was looking to use CSS to format it and my logical idea was to just embed it or find a way to output the actual output I have such as the GET function I used to send data?

Comment: @RiggsFolly The issue is that when using the PHP shown above, it simply just displays the code not the values I want to show

Comment: What does the URL in the browser address bar look like? Does it start `http://` or `file:///`

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is hosted externally through my Academy's own server therefore http://

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question properly, you want to output data from a PHP file so that it's visible to a user. To do this you need to do the following:

1. Create a php file `index.php`
2. Add your HTML and PHP code
3. Ensure your web server is running

   - `php -S localhost:8080`
4. Open the URL in your browser http://localhost:8080

Let's say your `index.php` file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Foo</li>
        <?php

            $source = array(1,2,3,4,5);

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($source); $i++) {
                echo '<li>' . $i . '</li>';
            }

        ?>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The rendered result looks like this:

- Foo
- 0
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

Comment: When I change my current HTML document to a .php file it doesn't run at all?

Comment: @AlexJenkinson see miken32's answer regarding syntax errors. Also, ensure you have a php server (or some kind of server running). Check any errors in the logs/console window.